# Adding an image to content

Tags: php, function

I'm using this code to add tags to the end of a WP blog post:

```
    function tags_after_single_post_content($content) {
  $posttags = get_the_tags();
  if ($posttags) {
    $array = [];
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      $array[] = '<a href="/tag/' . $tag->slug . '/">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }
    $content .= 'Tags: ' . implode(', ', $array) . '<br>';
  }

  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'tags_after_single_post_content' );
```

but I'd like to insert an image instead of the word "Tags:" is this possible?

Comment: how is the image to be determined? The same image - always or some dynamic content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line in this way:

```
$content .= '<img src="path.jpg"> ' . implode(', ', $array) . '<br>';
```

Comment: @ A static image.  @Tommaso Thank you, this worked!